# How can I destructurize an object with a dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I destructurize custom hook {test, jsx} = useField()
I can destructurize only test and jsx automatically
But I want to get also [code]: value, [`set${code}`]: setValue (it should be date and setDate), but it doesn't work

Is it possible?

```
export const useField = ({
    code,
    fieldType,
    label,
    type,
}: FilterFieldProps) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<Date | null>(null)

    const jsx = (
        <FormGroup label={label}>
            {(() => {
                switch (fieldType) {
                    case 'datePicker':
                        return (
                            <DatePicker
                                onChange={(date) => {
                                    setValue(date)
                                }}
                                selected={value}
                            />
                        )
                }
            })()}
        </FormGroup>
    )
    const test = 'test'

    return { [test]: 'test', [code]: value, [`set${code}`]: setValue, jsx }
}
```

I want to destructurize automatically 2 dynamic variables. Is it possible?

Comment: `[test]: 'test'` should be `[test]: test`. Other than that, because you didn't explain what "it doesn't work" means, it's hard to know what else might be wrong. Do you get an error? Do you get an object that looks wrong?

Comment: You are creating a new object, not destructuring. Or I missunderstood something

Comment: You can't destructure to a name, but you can destructure the rest into another var.  eg.  `{test, jsx, ...other} = useField() `  `other` will then have the other props.  You could then do `other['settest']` to get them.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine

```js
function useField({ test, name, code }) {
  const jsx = `<b>:)</>`
  const setValue = () => {}
  const value = 123


  return { [test]: 'test', [code]: value, [`set${code}`]: setValue, jsx }
}

const { minecraft, secret, setsecret } = useField({ test: 'minecraft', code: 'secret', name: 'steve' })

console.log(minecraft, secret, setsecret)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use a string as a replacement name!